# Restore ImageView after setColorFilter

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I'm trying to add *DuoTone effect* to my app by changing the Color of `ImageView` using `setColorFilter`, I have two buttons **CANCEL** and **DONE**.

**CANCEL**: If the user applies one of the effects and decides to cancel, I want to set the previous `bitmap` in `ImageView`

Code :

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                originalImage = prevBitmap;
                fullImageView.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
                fullImageView.invalidate();
                hideViews();
            }
        });
```

**MY PROBLEM:** When I click on **CANCEL** button nothing happens, the ImageView does not change to the previous `bitmap`, the `setColorFilter` keeps applying, how I can restore/refresh/reset the `ImageView`

Comment: You can call clearColorFilter() for the same image object.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting prevBitmap?

Comment: @Bhavnik thank you so much, I didn't know about this method

Comment: @Azhar92 thank you for your comment, my problem solved

Comment: @pic : You're welcome. Did it work properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove color filter you've applied on image,

You can call clearColorFilter() for the same image object

For more info [clearColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#clearColorFilter())